# How to blacklist a USB device by UUID in GNOME (udev)?

Tags: usb, gnome, udev

I'm using GNOME 3, with udev.
How can I blacklist a specific USB drive by its UUID or label so that it doesn't mount automatically?

Answer (score 0):

So far I've not found how to do it by UUID. However [this article](http://www.worldofnubcraft.com/969/hide-your-disks-or-partitions-from-nautilus) says how to do it using the device name (sda?).